# Storing large amount data as a single JSON field - extract important fields to their own field?

Tags: mysql

I'm planning of storing a large amount of data from a user submitted form (around 100 questions) in a json field.

I will only need to access for queries for two pieces of data from the form, `name` and `type`.

Would it be advisable (and more efficient), to extract `name` and `type` to their own fields for querying or shall I just whack it all in one json field and query that json field since json searching is now supported?

Comment: Do you want to use JSON just because JSON searching is supported?

Comment: No - I just want somewhere to store 100 or so fields without specifically naming them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are concerned about performance, then maintaining separate fields for the `name` and `type` is probably the way to go here.  The reason for this is that if these two points of data exist as separate fields, it leaves open the possibility to do things like add indices to those columns.  While you *can* use MySQL's JSON API to query by `name` and `type`, it would most likely would never be able to compete with an index lookup, at least not in terms of performance.

From a storage point of view, you would not pay much of a price to maintain two separate columns.  The main price you would pay is that everytime the JSON gets updated, you would have to also update the `name` and `type` columns.